# How to pass selected uitableviewcell variable to previous viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

This is the first time I have tried to do this and I understand the concept of what I am trying to do but just not 100% sure on how to execute it.

I have a main view and a sub view.. the main view has several custom uitableviewcells each with a single textlabel. when the cell is selected it loads the subview onto the navigational stack, their is a list of standard uitableviews that I have loaded with values from the database.

When you select one of these uitableviewcells in the sub view, I want to capture that value pop the current view from the stack and then load the selected value of the subview into the main tableviews cell that was originally selected..

In the sub view I am thinking something along the lines of

```
MainViewController *mvc = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainViewController"  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
[mvc release];
```

But this obviously this isnt passing any values around...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use delegation, if you don't know how to use it, this link might help:

http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000075.php

So the general idea is that your main view will be the delegate of your subview, and the subview will tell it's delegate when a cell was tapped and pass in that variable (for example: [delegate cellChanged:cell];), then the main view (the delegate of the subview) will handle that.

Comment: okay cool, I thought so.. just didnt know that I could use my main view as a delegate..